# Translating Language programmatically

Tags: swift, localization

Just hopped into the world a multiLanguage settings in Xcode/Swift. After a good view on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/localization-in-ios-applications-46df5959a588) I found it very easy to setting up multiple language using the Xcode Base Internationalization (Storyboards). The only problem is I have a progammatically UICollectionView which I don't get to see using the language string file. My titles for my UICollectionView is setup through a LET:

```
let titles = ["TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3", " TITLE4", "TITLE5", "TITLE6", "TITLE7",  "TITLE8", "TITLE9", "TITLE10"]
```

I want to translate the title#'s. But I can't add those to the language string file can I? (Because I don't know the objectID's of those title's? because they are not on my storyboard?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: Although this answer works good, if you want an easier tutorial or you want to know more about the topic, I suggest reading [my article](https://medium.com/@federicabenacquista/localizing-an-ios-app-programmatically-made-easy-526f19f664d5) instead.**

Go to Project > Info and check `Use Base Internationalization`.

[image: Check "Use Base Internationalization" at bottom of Info page]

Then, in the localization table, add the languages you wish to use. After adding them they should appear like this:

[image: Multiple localized .strings files in different languages]

Now create a new Swift file, and inside there, add all the strings you want to convert like this:

```
//First the text to display then a comment to describe what the string means
let editStr = NSLocalizedString("Edit" , comment: "Action to modify an element")
```

Now, in your base file (assuming that is in english), for each string you have write:

```
"Edit" = "Edit";
```

The first string must be exactly the one you put in your `NSLocalizedString` before, the second one is the translation (which can be different obviously). **It is fundamental** to put the `;` at the end of each contiguous line;

Now in your other files (for example in the Italian one), you'll put the exact same code of the previous file but on the right side you'll have the translation:

```
"Edit" = "Modifica";
```

When you have to assign a title to something, you assign the one you declared in your file (ie. `editStr`).

That's pretty much all you need to know.

To immediately test the results click on the name of your app (next to the run button) and click on edit scheme, go to Run > Options > App language and change it to the language you want.

---

For your specific case, declare multiple `NSLocalizedString` for each title you have:

```
let title1 = NSLocalizedString("TITLE1" , comment: "Title1")
let title2 = NSLocalizedString("TITLE2" , comment: "Title2")
let title3 = NSLocalizedString("TITLE3" , comment: "Title3")
```

and so on...
Then you will add them in your base file and in your translated ones as I showed you above.

When it comes to the `UIViewController` where you put your `UICollectionView`, you declare your array as follows:

```swift
let titles =[title1, title2, title3]
```

This picture is from the link you sent me:
[image]
You declare your array like:

```swift
let titles = ["TITLE1"...]
```

while you should do it like:

```swift
let titles = [TITLE1...]
```

where `TITLE1` is the name of the localized string

Comment: Very nice @Marybnq! I understand your answer, but the thing is I have a programmatically UICollectionView with a 'withReuseIdentifier' which reads my `let titles = ["TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3", " TITLE4", "TITLE5", "TITLE6", "TITLE7",  "TITLE8", "TITLE9", "TITLE10"]` from `label.text = titles[indexPath.row]` Now I don't know how to assign ie `editStr` because your example breaks my `label.text = titles[indexPath.row]`

Comment: You should create different NSLocalizedString s with every title you have. in your titles constants, instead of writing "title1" acc, you write the name of your NSLocalizedString. I'm updating my answer

Comment: Allright, again thank you for your time @Marybnq ! I've been trying for 4 days now to get it work but I can't seem to figure out where I go wrong. Must be something stupid. A short explanation of the things I did; I enabled the `Use Base Internationalization` then I added a new string file named  `Localizable.strings` and selected the languages with the file inspector. Added all the `"key" = "value";` to it. Now where do I put the `let title1 = NSLocalizedString("TITLE1" , comment: "Title1")` ? You were saying to create a new swift file for this? Does it has to have a specific name? Thanks aga

Comment: no problem. just put it in a regular swift file with the name you want

Comment: OK, tried that but I don't have any effect.. Check out my [link] (https://i.ibb.co/5xnCPSM/Untitled-2.jpg) Scr#1 is my Localizable.swift where I put all the NSLocalizedStrings. Scr#2 My String files, each have the same items but other translations. Scr#3 Localizable.swift again .. Scr#4 my function which reads the  titles[indexPath.row] and scr#5 the let titles. Do I leave the last one like that or do I need to point to the NSLocalizedStrings somehow?

Comment: In your titles array you put strings, not the localizabe items, check my answer again to se how i declare my array

Comment: I feel so stupid.. :) Thank you, thank you for your time, for the correct explanation and your patience. Forza Italia! :)

Comment: Ahahahahhahah don't worry it was my pleasure!